# Groovy: parsing file for mysql database changes

Tags: parsing, text, groovy

i have a text file with content:

```
ACTION = NEW        // (NEW, CHANGE)
NEW_NUMBER = '123456'
NUMBER_FOR_CHANGE = '789456'
TEXT_NAME1 = 'TEST1'
TEXT_NAME2 = 'TEST2'
TEXT_NAME3 = 'TEST3'
```

and i want make a code on Groovy script for parsing this file and making next changes:

if action = new:

```
`sql.executeInsert "INSERT INTO TABLE.DB (NUMBER, NAME1, NAME2, NAME3) VALUES ($NEW_NUMBER, $TEXT_NAME1, $TEXT_NAME2, $TEXT_NAME3)" `
```

if action = change:

```
    sql.executeUpdate "UPDATE TABLE.DB SET NAME1 = $TEXT_NAME1, NAME2 = $TEXT_NAME2, NAME3 = $TEXT_NAME3 WHERE NUMBER LIKE $NUMBER_FOR_CHANGE"
```

if action = delete:

```
    sql.execute "DELETE FROM TABLE.DB WHERE NUMBER = $NUMBER_FOR_CHANGE"
```

I will be grateful for any help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it?

```
def sqlstr = new Properties().with { props ->
  new File( '/path/to/file' ).withReader { r ->
    load( r )
    switch( props.ACTION ) {
      case 'NEW':
        "INSERT INTO TABLE.DB (NUMBER, NAME1, NAME2, NAME3) VALUES ($NEW_NUMBER, $TEXT_NAME1, $TEXT_NAME2, $TEXT_NAME3)"
        break
      case 'CHANGE':
        "UPDATE TABLE.DB SET NAME1=$TEXT_NAME1, NAME2=$TEXT_NAME2, NAME3=$TEXT_NAME3 WHERE NUMBER = $NUMBER_FOR_CHANGE"
        break
      case 'DELETE':
        "DELETE FROM TABLE.DB WHERE NUMBER = $NUMBER_FOR_CHANGE"
        break
      default:
        throw new RuntimeException( "Unknown ACTION $props.ACTION" )
    }
  }
}

// Assuming sql is set up right:
sql.execute sqlstr
```

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown ACTION NEW // (NEW, CHANGE)

Comment: You're leaving the `// (NEW, CHANGE)` in there?  I thought that was just an example for this question?

Comment: this description of ACTION string. i will make same descriptions for each string in text file. Also, im planning use in script others defenitions like as ACTIO. As primet: ACTION2, which will start other sql-query

Comment: I didn't realise that and you didn't mention that...  Why not just prefix comments with `#` and have them on a separate line?  Then you can use the Properties code above, as that's the standard.  Otherwise you're writing your own file format for very little gain.

Comment: okay, i did as you recommend, now i have another error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown ACTION: NEW

Comment: i found problem: there are was space bar after NEW

Comment: when i try println $NEW_NUMBER after case 'NEW', i see $NEW_NUMBER is null

Comment: script is work but no takes parameters from text file like:  NEW_NUMBER, NUMBER_FOR_CHANGE, TEXT_NAME1 and etc .. and dont use '123456', '789456', 'TEST1' etc in sql script. this line is not work: "INSERT INTO TABLE.DB (NUMBER, NAME1, NAME2, NAME3) VALUES ($NEW_NUMBER, $TEXT_NAME1, $TEXT_NAME2, $TEXT_NAME3)". Script work if i using parameters not from file, like this: "INSERT INTO TABLE.DB (NUMBER, NAME1, NAME2, NAME3) VALUES ('123456', 'TEST1', 'TEST2', 'TEST3')"

Comment: try `$props.NEW_NUMBER`.  If that doesn't work, then are you sure the file is in the format you specified above?  Works here afaict.